# Sublime text: Process current buffer with Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, markdown

I have a Ruby script that can take a Markdown file and transform it to an output format I need.

I usually write these Markdown files using Sublime. I am looking for a simple way to run that particular Ruby script on the current buffer.

I was looking at [build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) but that seems incredibly complicated for what I need. Also, the problem is that the actual command I am running is "ruby" and it has two arguments:

```
ruby process_markdown.rb (current_file).md
```

And the "process_markdown.rb" file is in the Packages/User folder.

So... am I supposed to use a Build System for this? Or is there a simpler way? If build system, could you point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to write a `.sublime-build` for your Markdown files.

Something like

```
{
  "cmd": ["/full/path/to/ruby/ /full/path/to/process_markdown.rb", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.md"
}
```